# How to run XMPP Room Join & Invite process in background Thread in iOS

Tags: xmppframework

I have got an issue with Room join & Inviting members to XMPP Room in iOS.
I have a clause that needs to join 200 rooms together at login, I did it but it blocks the main thread.
Can anyone suggest the Approach to handle hundreds of room joining seemless without blocking main thread.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why did you join 200 rooms at a time in the first place?

My guess you need to join so that be able to get all group chats?  This is a very inefficient way.  I think you need to implement `Offline Message` `Push Notification`.

Look into [ejabberd_mod_offline_post](https://github.com/diamondbybold/ejabberd_mod_offline_post)

1. First config the Room must be a Member-Only room, and add all users as members right after you created it, so that be able to get a total.
2. Add above model into ejabberd models.
3. Implement a Callback Service to handle the callback post.

The idea is when User go offline:

- In one-to-one case, offline_message_hook will be raised
- In MUC case, muc_filter_message will be raised, and any one not Presence-Available is offline.